# xmpp error on google app engine with python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, xmpp

I have my server running on GAE with Python. I am using xmpp for sending notifications to gtalk users. I see this error most often:

```
_ah/xmpp/message/error/
```

Is it happening because the client is not supported or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error that was sent to you by the receiver of your message.  You might consider adding some [error handling for this URL](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/xmpp/overview#Handling_Error_Stanzas).